# How to update and insert in pyspark?

Tags: python, sql, pyspark

I have two Dataframs
df1 =

| col1 | col2 | loaddate | lastupdatedate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 12/02/21 | 12/02/21 |
| b | 2 | 12/02/21 | 12/02/21 |
| c | 3 | 12/02/21 | 12/02/21 |
| d | 4 | 12/02/21 | 12/02/21 |
| e | 5 | 12/02/21 | 12/02/21 |

df2

| col1 | col2 | loaddate | lastupdatedate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 10 | 12/12/21 | 12/12/21 |
| f | 2 | 12/12/21 | 12/12/21 |
| g | 3 | 12/12/21 | 12/12/21 |

the result df looking for is

| col1 | col2 | loaddate | lastupdatedate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 10 | 12/02/21 | 12/12/21 |
| b | 2 | 12/02/21 | 12/02/21 |
| c | 3 | 12/02/21 | 12/02/21 |
| d | 4 | 12/02/21 | 12/02/21 |
| e | 5 | 12/02/21 | 12/02/21 |
| f | 2 | 12/12/21 | 12/12/21 |
| g | 3 | 12/12/21 | 12/12/21 |

in the result df there is an update and insert happening(please look at first row)

Answer (score 0):

If you concatenate them in order, so that the second df is last, then you know the order when you do a groupby.  So you should be able to just use `.first` and `.last` on the columns in the way you want.

```
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from functools import reduce
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df3 = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, [df1,df2])

df3 = df3.groupby('col1').agg(F.last('col2').alias('col2'), 
                              F.first('loaddate').alias('loaddate'),
                              F.last('lastupdatedate').alias('lastupdatedate'))
```

Output

```
+----+----+--------+--------------+
|col1|col2|loaddate|lastupdatedate|
+----+----+--------+--------------+
|   a|  10|12/02/21|      12/12/21|
|   b|   2|12/02/21|      12/02/21|
|   c|   3|12/02/21|      12/02/21|
|   d|   4|12/02/21|      12/02/21|
|   e|   5|12/02/21|      12/02/21|
|   f|   2|12/12/21|      12/12/21|
|   g|   3|12/12/21|      12/12/21|
+----+----+--------+--------------+
```

Comment: what if i chnged by df2 to below table and need the same result                                      | col1 | col2 |
|:---- |:------:|
| a  | 10    |
| f  | 2    | 
| g  | 3    |

Comment: i mean without the loaddate and lastupdate col. Always i need to go this on tables that are large in size